# Sorting is not working on any column other than primary column in yii2 kartik grid

Tags: yii2, gridview-sorting

I have all set and filtering is working fine but facing problem in sorting columns
When I set sort for id column it works fine but when I set other columns sort, it is not working

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,

        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 50,
        ],

    ]);

    $dataProvider->sort->attributes['id'] = [
            'asc' => ['challan.id' => SORT_ASC],
            'desc' => ['challan.id' => SORT_DESC],
        ];
        $dataProvider->sort->attributes['studentname'] = [
            'asc' => ['student.studentName' => SORT_ASC],
            'desc' => ['student.studentName' => SORT_DESC],
        ];
        $dataProvider->sort->attributes['sid'] = [
            'asc' => ['challan.sid' => SORT_ASC],
            'desc' => ['challan.sid' => SORT_DESC],
        ];
```

Please tell me what is wrong with this code
Thanks in advance

Comment: add gridview code

Comment: We need to see more about you $query variable.

Comment: $query = Challan::find()->Where(['challan.id' => Challan::find()->select(['MAX(id)'])
                ->where(['student.campus_id' => $authitems])
                ->groupBy('sid')])->orderBy(['challan.id'=>SORT_DESC]);

Comment: please add the information in your Question, and try adding the complete search model rather than copy/pasting the code chunks, to sort the problem it is necessary that you provide the code base as is,

Comment: Thanks @MuhammadOmerAslam Aslam It is my fault because I am new in it. Now my problem solved Thanks

Comment: no issues it's ok , just wanted to guide you so that you can get better replies to your problem next time , cheers you fixed it yourself

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem actually it is because I have used orderBy in $query variable

```
orderBy(['challan.id'=>SORT_DESC])
```

Comment: and that `orderBy(['challan.id'=>SORT_DESC])` statement is nowhere ? in your provided code, please try to add complete codebase next time when posting a question.